# Sed to regex column names

Tags: regex, sed

I have a SQL logfile with lots of SELECT statements with lots of columns. I want to replace the column names with *.

So

want to change `SELECT T.A, T.B, T.B, T.C FROM TABLE T`  to `SELECT T.* FROM TABLE T`

so I can to

```
s/T\.[A-Z_]*//g
```

will get T. column names and replace them with nothing.

```
s/T\.[A-Z_]*/T.*/g
```

Will do...

```
SELECT T.*, T.*, T.*, T.*
```

instead of

```
SELECT T.*
```

So how do I capture everything between the SELECT AND FROM and then replace it with T.*?

Thanks

Comment: Try `sed 's/\<T.*\( FROM\)/T.*\1/g'`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/U34up5).

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try:

```
sed 's/ \([A-Z]\.\).*\(FROM.*\)/ \1* \2/g'
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT T.* FROM TABLE T
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be using a placeholder for an alias if it is possible for an alias to be something different than letter `T`:

```
sed -r 's/([[:alnum:]_]+)\.[^ ,]+(, *\1\.[^ ,]+)+/\1.*/g' file
```